# Yii model generation

Tags: php, yii, gii

you know that using gii tool we can generate models and view controllers, so, the question is :
Is it possible to generate a model without using the gii tool, I mean, just doing it through the php code like calling some method giving required parameters to it and so on?

Comment: you can create without gii

Comment: so how to do that without gii?

Comment: Models are just a class file, if you copy the format of another one, make sure the name is unique and the same for the class declaration as well as the filename, put it in the models folder, then it will work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a model called company, create a file named Company.php in models folder  and add the following

```
namespace app\models;

use yii\db\ActiveRecord;

class Company extends ActiveRecord {
 // add your functions and properties here

}
```

**N.B. : This is for the latest version of Yii, ie Yii 2.0**